# Button I created for a Google Sign In activity won't allow me to login

Tags: android, xml, google-signin

As I mentioned above, I created a Google Sign In button for Android, but I also created a Sign Out button and a Sign Out and Disconnect button, but when I click on the buttons in the app nothing actually happens. I'll paste my SignInActivity class below as well as my login.xml layout resource file.

***SignInActivity***

```
package com.example.gcsd.gcsdapp;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.example.gcsd.gcsdapp.R;
import android.net.Uri;

public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private TextView mStatusTextView;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);


findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);


GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();

SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) 
findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();

OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = 
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
if (opr.isDone()) {


    Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
    GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
    handleSignInResult(result);
} else {

    showProgressDialog();
    opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
        }
    });
}
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    GoogleSignInResult result = 
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
    handleSignInResult(result);
}
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
if (result.isSuccess()) {

    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
    mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, 
acct.getDisplayName()));
    updateUI(true);
} else {

    updateUI(false);
}
}

private void signIn() {
Intent signInIntent = 
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

private void signOut() {
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {

                updateUI(false);

            }
        });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {

                updateUI(false);

            }
        });
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
if (mProgressDialog == null) {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
}

mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
    mProgressDialog.hide();
}
}

private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
if (signedIn) {
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.sign_in_button:
        signIn();
        break;
    case R.id.sign_out_button:
        signOut();
        break;
    case R.id.disconnect_button:
        revokeAccess();
        break;
}
}
}
```

***login.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.gcsd.gcsdapp.SignInActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<Button
android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sign Out"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/disconnect_button"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_in_button" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/disconnect_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Disconnect"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/sign_out_button"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_in_button" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/sign_out_and_disconnect"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sign Out and Disconnect"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_out_button"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sign_out_button"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/guideline"
app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="20dp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/status"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Status"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/sign_out_and_disconnect"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_in_button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
android xml
```

Comment: Do you have a log, an error or something?

Comment: @ArnaudPradier there is no error. The program runs, but when I click on the button nothing pops up prompting me to log in, and when I hit log out I am still in my account that I signed into on my virtual device prior to creating this application.